# In facebook apps how link is associated with apps link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

Suppose I have facebook apps, and its canvas url is `http://localhost/app/`, and this page contains a link as `<a href='/a.php'>go</a>`, when this show in apps page in facebook then it shows me the link as `http://localhost/app/a.php`, how make it related with my facebook apps, such it would show `http://apps.facebook.com/testappasdf/a.php` instead of `http://localhost/app/a.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration file make a variable or constant and assign it a value of your application address. For example in your config file you define a new constant

```
define('APPURL','http://apps.facebook.com/testappasdf');
```

then where you create a link we make it like this `<a target='_top' href="<?php echo APPURL?>/a.php">Test Link</a>`

Comment: Can u please give me a real world example? It shows nothing when click on that link.